# how to animate height only on top half of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why `test` here has padding top and bottom if css says: `padding:0`?

But the main question is - clicking on the button there is no height animation of the digit - just the background is animated.

I need to animate `hieght` of the digit but so that **only lower half** of the digit remains visible.

i.e. top half of `7` should be cutted.

Is it possible?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
let half = $('#test').height() / 2;
$('#test').animate({height: half}, 500);
})
```

```css
#test{
position:absolute;
font-size:14vw;
font-weight:bold;
background:gold;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#btn{
margin-left:54px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>7</div>
<br>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting @Azeem Aslam's answer increasing height of overlay from 1 px to half the size of the `#test` div

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let half = $('#test').height() / 2;
  $('#overlay').animate({
    height: half
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: gold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  line-height:0.74;
}

#btn {
  margin-left: 54px;
}

#overlay {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'><div id="overlay"></div>7</div>
<br>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: @qadenza i did not get your question do you not want the white space on top after the animation?

Comment: no, yellow space between background and black digit on top and bottom - how to remove them?

Comment: @qadenza check now i have added ```line-height``` property to ```#test``` you can increase decrease it to adjust the space as much as you want

Comment: @qadenza ```line-height:0.74;``` works fine with your font size which is ```14vw```

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow-y:hidden;` to css to hide the overflowing area:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
let half = $('#test').height() / 2;
$('#test').animate({height: half}, 500);
})
```

```css
#test{
overflow-y:hidden;
position:absolute;
font-size:14vw;
font-weight:bold;
background:gold;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#btn{
margin-left:54px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>7</div>
<br>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: please read carefuly the post - `only lower half of the digit remains visible` - so the reverse

Answer (score 2):

As per your need you need to hide digit from top so you can add an overlay to on the top and increase it's height on click. That will hide digit

I have added css for overlay. If you need any other change ping me :)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let half = $('#overlay').height() * 2;
  $('#overlay').animate({
    height: half
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: gold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#btn {
  margin-left: 54px;
}

#overlay {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'><div id="overlay"></div>7</div>
<br>
<button id='btn'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: doesn't work. digit is entrirely visible after click

Comment: Plz run now overlay covers digit gradually updated code and it stays hidden dosen't matter how many times u click.
or elaborate lil bit more.

Comment: simply - click is dead

Comment: plz reload page I have updated code to make click work. Click is working for me and on click it increases the height of overlay to hide parent div.